# Using Docker and connectors to connect kafka to spark, spark to cassandra and kafka to cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-kafka, docker-compose, connector

**Detail:** We have dockerized `Kafka`, `Cassandra` and `Spark`, using `wurstmeister/kafka`, `strapdata/elassandra` and `bde2020/spark-master` images in docker-compose.

What we want to do is to connect the following using connectors:

- Kafka stream to Spark stream
- Spark stream to Cassandra
- Kafka stream to Cassandra

The problem is that we don't know whether it works fine or not, because these technologies sounds new for us.

**Graphical Representation:**

[image]

**Important Files:**

> docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  spark:
    container_name: spark
    image: bde2020/spark-master
    ports: 
      - 9180:8080
      - 9177:7077
      - 9181:8081
    links: 
      - elassandra
    volumes:
hosein:/var/lib/docker/volumes/data/python
      - /home/mostafa/Desktop/kafka-test/together/cassandra/mostafa-hosein:/var/lib/docker/volumes/data/python



  elassandra:
    image: strapdata/elassandra
    container_name: elassandra
    build: /home/mostafa/Desktop/kafka-test/together/cassandra
    env_file:
      - /home/mostafa/Desktop/kafka-test/together/cassandra/conf/cassandra.env
    volumes:
      - /home/mostafa/Desktop/kafka-test/together/cassandra/jarfile:/var/lib/docker/volumes/data/_data
    ports:
      - '7000:7000'
      - '7001:7001'
      - '7199:7199'
      - '9042:9042'
      - '9142:9142'
      - '9160:9160'
      - '9200:9200'
      - '9300:9300'

  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"

  kafka:
    build: .
    container_name: kafka
    links:
     - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_OPTS: -javaagent:/usr/app/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar=7071:/usr/app/prom-jmx-agent-config.yml
      CONNECTORS: elassandra
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    depends_on: 
      - elassandra

  kafka_connect-cassandra:
    image: datamountaineer/kafka-connect-cassandra
    container_name: kafka-connect-cassandra
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
      - 9102:9102
    environment: 
      - connect.cassandra.contact.points=localhost
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT =  "zookeeper:2181"
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS= "kafka:9092"
      - connect.cassandra.port=9042
      - connector.class=com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraSinkConnector
      - tasks.max=1
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - elassandra
```

> Dockerfile

```
FROM wurstmeister/kafka
ADD prom-jmx-agent-config.yml /usr/app/prom-jmx-agent-config.yml
ADD jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.10.jar /usr/app/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar
COPY wait-for-it.sh /wait-for-it.sh
RUN chmod +x /wait-for-it.sh
CMD ["/wait-for-it.sh", "zookeeper:2181", "--", "start-kafka.sh"]
```

**Example:** As an example I have added `CONNECTOR: elassandra` to environment variables of kafka's container but I haven't faced with any error and not sure whether it is a valid environment variable or not!

How do we can validate environment variables and test the connectors working fine?

Comment: `CONNECTORS` doesn't do anything for the kafka container... *Kafka Connect* would have to be a separate container

Comment: @cricket_007 I found an image without any helpful documentation, I mean [datamountaineer/kafka-connect-cassandra](https://hub.docker.com/r/datamountaineer/kafka-connect-cassandra). Do you have any idea how to connect kafka to cassandra using this image? Cause I have run kafka and cassandra images separately.

Comment: I haven't used that one. I typically use the confluentinc images, however I don't think those include Cassandra. The documentation without Docker is here https://docs.lenses.io/connectors/sink/cassandra.html  but Kafka Connect API itself can be found on Apache or Confluent sites

Comment: @cricket_007 confluentinc images aren’t found on docker hub anymore!

Comment: @MostafaGhadimi can you clarify what you're actually asking here? Is it the configuration details for Docker? Or conceptually how to use these three technologies together? For example Kafka->Cassandra is done well using Kafka Connect, if you're using Kafka Streams then why also Spark Streaming, etc.

Comment: Confluent images are on Docker Hub at https://hub.docker.com/u/confluentinc/

Comment: Have you ever checked that link recently @RobinMoffatt?
I face with Page Not Found error!

Comment: @cricket_007 I have edited the post and using `datamountaineer/kafka-connect-cassandra` image. I executed docker-compose without any issue. Do you have any idea about how can I make sure about the integrity of connection between Kafka and Cassandra?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I have edited the post and using datamountaineer/kafka-connect-cassandra image. I executed docker-compose without any issue. Do you have any idea about how can I make sure about the integrity of connection between Kafka and Cassandra?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, `CONNECTORS` is not a valid variable for the Kafka container. Kafka Connect is a separate service from the broker, so needs to be a separate container.

Kafka Connect [exposes a REST API](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/references/restapi.html) at port 8083.

You need to perform HTTP requests using `curl`, Postman, etc. to provide Connectors; they cannot be loaded just from variables.

I am not immediately aware of any specific properties needed for the Datamountainer containers, but they are built on top of the Confluent images, and you can find all those environment variables here - https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/5.1.2-post/examples/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml#L64-L86

These are for Kafka container, not Kafka Connect since they start with `KAFKA_`

```
  - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT =  "zookeeper:2181"
  - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS= "kafka:9092
```

And these are for the *connector properties* (which would be POSTed via JSON), not Environment variables.

```
  - connect.cassandra.contact.points=localhost
  - connect.cassandra.port=9042
  - connector.class=com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraSinkConnector
  - tasks.max=1
```

Then, `localhost` shouldn't be used anywhere in these properties; if you want Connect container to reach Cassandra, you would use `"connect.cassandra.contact.points": "elassandra"` (the docker service name)